# Protect Downloads directory in Asp.net MVC + identity application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

While waiting for solutions to my similar problem ([Self-hosted Owin, static files and authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550907/self-hosted-owin-static-files-and-authentication)) I would like to protect a directory serving static files within an MVC application with Asp.net Identity.
How can I protect my Downloads directory but still keeping all goodness of MVC and Identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite easy and obvious: just add a Web.config with desired authorizations.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

That was also my first immediate attempt, but I had forgotten to correctly set the **Copy to output directory** property.